# Constantly getting 401 when trying to post to Tumblr blog

Tags: tumblr

I'm getting a 401 constantly without further explanation of what the error is when posting to Tumblr via the v2 API.

Requests are below - linebreaks are added for readibility

```
POST http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/[blog].tumblr.com/post HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: api.tumblr.com
Content-Length: 303

body=test&
oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
oauth_nonce=4712451&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_timestamp=1312610497&
oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&
oauth_version=1.0&
type=text&
oauth_signature=ccN%2f0E%2bat42BAzdkDPJ%2ffcuMacY%3d
```

I get the following response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized
Date: Sat, 06 Aug 2011 06:01:43 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="ALL ADM DEV PSAi COM OUR OTRo STP IND ONL"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Tumblr-Usec: D=38791
Content-Length: 60
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

Does anyone can spot why?

Comment: I solved this problem by providing a non-blank tumblr secret - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849819/tumblr-oauth-image-post-gives-me-401-invalid-oauth-credentials/7141120#7141120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your base string here

http://quonos.nl/oauthTester/

and you can check everything here

http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/authentication/

Also, personally I've had some trouble when my signature included a +, as yours does above, (+ = %2b urlencoded). I solved the problem by testing for the + in my signature and re-signing if it did.

Comment: Hi Chris, i am getting 401(Not Authorized) in Tumblr post reblog api call, other tumblr apis are working fine. api response : {"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}.

Comment: In my case I received a 401 due to forgetting to include the oauth_token_secret obtained during the 1st step. Didn't even think to look for it since they reference twitter's API which doesn't use it.