# oAuth Post fails for Tumblr API (401 error)

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

This is the json request I am using,

```
http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/samarthsave1.tumblr.com/post?oauth_consumer_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oauth_nonce=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oauth_signature=14RMDFmQbzWRKPvfrijQRf%2FoNqY%3D
&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
&oauth_timestamp=1347387190
&oauth_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&oauth_version=1.0
&title=This%20test
&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com
&description=asd%20as%20asdasas%20ad%20a
&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
&type=link
```

I passing following headers

{"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization":"OAuth","Accept": "*/*"}

I am getting

```
{"meta":{"status":401,"msg":"Not Authorized"},"response":[]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965216/constantly-getting-401-when-trying-to-post-to-tumblr-blog) can be useful.

Comment: No. I went through all these existing posts but could not find a promising answer.

Comment: A few things: 1) You can take out the `api_key` parameter because it's not needed. 2) Are you certain those parameters are in the right order? 3) Are you certain you have a working Access Token? Have you been able to do something simple like fetching a user's info?

Comment: What was your resolution to this issue? Finding lots of other folks having the same 401 problem during posting (but other actions like /user/info work fine), but nobody is posting the fix.

Comment: @trackpopular did you get your solution if not try tumblr SDK :https://github.com/tumblr/TMTumblrSDK#authentication