# Why am I unauthorized in tumblr even on the api console?

Tags: tumblr

This is written in the example output (objective c):

> {   "meta": {
>       "status": 401,
>       "msg": "Not Authorized"   },   "response": [] }

What could be the problem?

Comment: It could be that you haven't authenticated. Have you?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It might help if you post some code.

Comment: To both the OP and the person who posted the bounty: This question has seen 695 views, so it's hardly "not receiving attention" - you just haven't given enough information for us to do anything but wonder and speculate. You've got to give us more to work with here.

Comment: Have you authenticated? Are you being rate-limited? Are you allowed to access that API endpoint using your credentials? There are a lot of things that we don't know here. Please give us more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have much to work with here since nobody has posted any code to examine for issues, but I'll try to address the question in a general sense:

It's highly unlikely that this is caused by some kind of bug in the Tumblr API. It's much more likely that it's caused either by some missed step in the authentication process, or a typo, or some kind of minor error. Here's a link to [a previous question regarding this 401 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819930/tumblr-api-authentification-401-error), and the problem was traced back to a typographical error. Here's [another question on the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965216/constantly-getting-401-when-trying-to-post-to-tumblr-blog?rq=1), where an answer mentions an issue with a plus sign in the signature as well as providing some resources for further troubleshooting. It's likely that the issues causing the same error for other people are similar, and cannot be confirmed except by a thorough proofreading of the code involved.

If, however, someone reading this believes that they're experiencing a deeper issue, they should feel free to provide a code sample which could be used to explore other possible explanations.

Comment: There is no real coding going on. I am experiencing this from the tumblr api console.